# How do you reassign the value of a variable from within a defined function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. Here is a basic example of my issue.

```
spam='spam'

def change():
    spam='eggs'

change()

print(spam)
```

This code will print 'spam' to the console. Is there a way to make this work without using return or arguments. Thank you.

Comment: put `global spam` in your function, although note this is not always good practise

Comment: I just want to reiterate Chris_Rands warning: this approach is usually not the best way. It will make your code difficult to reason about and difficult to maintain.

Comment: The variables in your function should stay in your function. And the inverse is also true, you should always try not to use global variables (if your function needs something, there most often is a way for you not to use a global variable)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to only use it when necessary

Answer (score 0):

Add `global spam` inside your `def` to target the variable defined outside of the method definition, or **better yet**, assign a new value from the result of the method:

```
spam = "spam"
def change(): return 'eggs'
spam = change() #spam now contains 'eggs'
```

However if you pass lists or dictionaries, modifying the value inside the method does affect the outside value too but that's a different story. IF you want to try it, use `spam=["spam"]` and inside the method do `spam[0] = 'eggs'`. There's no need for globals or assignments outside the method for this case.

Comment: But that's bad, you should have said it (and it's most often possible to do without it)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me as i have multiple variables being changed and I need them to be accessed from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
spam='spam'

def change():
    global spam
    spam='eggs'

change()

print(spam)
```